# How to create Nodes using jsPlumb community edition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, jsplumb

I am using the `@jsplumb/browser-ui` to create some `Nodes` within my `Nuxtjs/Vuejs`  application like as mentioned in their [documentation](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demonstration/flowchart). But I would like to create the Nodes at run-time. I am unable to do it.

I would like to create the `nodes/rectangle` shapes whenever the user clicks on the `Add Event` button. So rather than creating the `Nodes` static way I would like to create it dynamically/run time based on the button click. I am not understanding how to do it using `jsPlumb` [documentation](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/demonstration/flowchart) how to do it as they don't have a specific code sample to achieve the same.

Following is something I would like to achieve:
[image: CPT2111081318-1890x906]

Code I have so far:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="addConnector()">
            Add Connector
          </button>&nbsp;
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="addNode()">
            Add Event
          </button>&nbsp;
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" @click="submitEvents()">
            Submit
          </button>&nbsp;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row root">
        <div class="col-md-12 body">
          <div id="diagram" ref="diagram" class="diagram" style="position: relative; width:100%; height:100%;" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      nodeCounter: 0,
      nodeArray: [],
      connectorCounter: 0,
      connectorArray: [],
      allEventsInfoArray: []
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    const vm = this
    if (process.browser) {
      const JSPlumb = await require('@jsplumb/browser-ui')
      JSPlumb.ready(function () {
        const instance = JSPlumb.newInstance({
          container: vm.$refs.diagram
        })
        console.log(instance)
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    // On click of Add Node button create the draggable node into the jsPlumb canvas
    addNode () {
      // const container = "<button class='btn btn-info' id='container_" + this.nodeCounter + "'></button>"
      this.nodeCounter++
    },
    // On click of Add Connector button create the draggable node into the jsPlumb canvas
    addConnector () {
      console.log('Add Connector : ')
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.root {
  --bg-color: #fff;
  --line-color-1: #D5D8DC;
  --line-color-2: #a9a9a9;
}

.body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.diagram {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  background-image: conic-gradient(at calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 2px),var(--line-color-1) 270deg, #0000 0),
    conic-gradient(at calc(100% - 1px) calc(100% - 1px),var(--line-color-2) 270deg, #0000 0);
  background-size: 100px 100px, 20px 20px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing the answer as it can be helpful to someone in the future:

As per the response from contributors [GitHub](https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb/issues/1068), we won't be able to create the `Nodes/Shapes` within the `Jsplumb community edition`.

Instead of `Jsplumb`, I started using the `DrawFlow` library which is just awesome and has all the requirements that I needed for my application.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning DrawFlow, it was what I was looking for.